# Prompt user to share a Dropbox folder with another user

Tags: dropbox-api

The Dropbox API does not provide access to folder sharing, but for an app I am developing, I would at least like to be able to prompt a user to share a folder with another person. At the moment the best I can do is to direct them to the sharing page.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/share
```

Is there any way I could make this easier for the user, for instance by selecting the particular folder and (perhaps) filling in the email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user is signed in to Dropbox, you can use links of this format:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/home/FOLDERNAME?shareoptions=1
```

Replace FOLDERNAME with the URL-encoded representation of the shared folder name (e.g., "My Folder" becomes "My%20Folder").

This gets you to the sharing screen at least; the user still needs to type in the email address.